# unauthorized devices appear in windows 10 network drive SMB

Tags: windows, wifi, wireless, smb

Few days ago I was trying to access a shared folder via SMB on Windows File Explorer and noticed 3 strange mobile phone devices appear listed in the network drive. I never owned any of the mobile devices that listed in the drive

Being the only person using my home wifi network nobody accesses my network resources

The Phone listed in the screenshot is the suspicious device that had me wonder how is it in the network
[image]

My question is 
How would you investigate if noticed unauthorized devices (mobile phones or laptops) appear in your windows 10 network drive ?

Comment: You have not described a compromised SMB. Did you intend to?

Comment: Where did you see these devices?

Comment: I saw them appear on the windows file explorer as i was browsing the network resources like when you try to access a shared printer or shared folder via SMB on the windows file explorer thats where the 3 unauthorized devices appeared.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as "too broad", as it doesn't actually define one question. It's a description of a situation, with the general undertone of "What should I do now?". The problem is that none of us can say for sure.

Comment: "root cause" of what?

Comment: Despite the story about how you discovered the devices, your question does not appear to be about SMB at all, but about wifi security.

Comment: I will try to fix the question,

Comment: *Where* did they appear? Can you provide a screenshot? How do you know they were mobile devices? What do you mean by "listed in the network drive"?

Comment: @vidarlo i attached a screenshot, tried my best to explain the situation this is what i was seeing on windows file explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing, in any network, is to check the access logs. What connected to those shares? From there, you gather as much information as you can on the devices/users connecting. That's how you investigate.

Monitoring wifi for unauthorised devices is usually done on the WiFi AP. But it is usually better to have the strongest encryption and a strong passphrase to join the network.

Comment: I resolved it , but still appreciate your reply, it turned out to be a Windows 10 feature called Windows Connect Now.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was a Windows 10 feature called Windows Connect Now (WCN). I resolved it by disabling the service of Windows Connect Now and no longer see 
 random / unauthorized devices appear in the Windows Network in  ‘File Explorer’.

source https://appuals.com/fix-unknown-strange-devices-showing-network/